# Find the number of observations since the opposite event occured in R using datatables

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, datatables

I am hoping to create a new variable in datatable that adds a column telling me the number of days since the opposite (or other event occured).

The dataset I have looks like the following:

```
  date     event  id obs_since_event_1 obs_since_event_2
2000-07-06     2  1        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     1  1        NA                 1
2000-07-09     0  1        1                  2
2000-07-10     0  1        2                  3
2000-07-15     2  1        3                  4
2000-07-16     1  1        4                  1
2000-07-20     0  1        1                  2
2000-07-21     1  1        2                  3
2000-07-06     1  2        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     2  2        1                  NA
2000-07-15     0  2        2                  1
2000-07-16     0  2        3                  2
2000-07-17     2  2        4                  3
2000-07-18     1  2        5                  1
```

And I am hoping to add a column called days_since_opposite. which records number of days since the opposite event occurred (the opposite events being 1 and 2). I already have the number of days since either an event 1 or 2 occurred. Now I need to work out an if statement that works in datatables that will provide me with the corresponding values in the final column.

```
  date     event  id obs_since_event_1 obs_since_event_2 days_since_opposite
2000-07-06     2  1        NA                 NA                  NA
2000-07-07     1  1        NA                 1                   NA
2000-07-09     0  1        1                  2                   NA
2000-07-10     0  1        2                  3                   NA
2000-07-15     2  1        3                  4                   3
2000-07-16     1  1        4                  1                   1
2000-07-20     0  1        1                  2                   NA
2000-07-21     1  1        2                  3                   3
```

I hope this is clear. I also have different ids to reckon with but not sure if it impacts the results.

I tried something along the following lines but it did not work:

```
data[,days_since_opposite:=ifelse(event==1,obs_since_event_2,ifelse(event==2,obs_since_event_1,0)),]
```

Thanks in advance

**DATA**

```
Input = (
  '  date     event  id obs_since_event_1 obs_since_event_2
2000-07-06     2  1        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     1  1        NA                 1
2000-07-09     0  1        1                  2
2000-07-10     0  1        2                  3
2000-07-15     2  1        3                  4
2000-07-16     1  1        4                  1
2000-07-20     0  1        1                  2
2000-07-21     1  1        2                  3
2000-07-06     1  2        NA                 NA
2000-07-07     2  2        1                  NA
2000-07-15     0  2        2                  1
2000-07-16     0  2        3                  2
2000-07-17     2  2        4                  3
2000-07-18     1  2        5                  1')
df = read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T)
```

Comment: Use `dput()` to wrap up your `data.table` so that we can work on it.

Comment: I am unable to do that, sorry

Comment: Then I am afraid it'll be tough to get help. You can at least read the documentation of `dput()`.

Comment: I believe the problem may be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
#identify the opposite event
DT[, oppev := c(0L, 2L, 1L)[event + 1L]]

#for event 1 and 2, perform non-equi join to find the prev opp event
DT[event %in% c(1L, 2L), days_since_opposite := DT[.SD, 
    on=.(id, event=oppev, date<date), mult="last", as.integer(i.date - x.date)]]
```

output:

```
          date event id oppev days_since_opposite
 1: 2000-07-06     2  1     1                  NA
 2: 2000-07-07     1  1     2                   1
 3: 2000-07-09     0  1     0                  NA
 4: 2000-07-10     0  1     0                  NA
 5: 2000-07-15     2  1     1                   8
 6: 2000-07-16     1  1     2                   1
 7: 2000-07-20     0  1     0                  NA
 8: 2000-07-21     1  1     2                   6
 9: 2000-07-06     1  2     2                  NA
10: 2000-07-07     2  2     1                   1
11: 2000-07-15     0  2     0                  NA
12: 2000-07-16     0  2     0                  NA
13: 2000-07-17     2  2     1                  11
14: 2000-07-18     1  2     2                   1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("date     event  id 
2000-07-06     2  1        
2000-07-07     1  1        
2000-07-09     0  1        
2000-07-10     0  1        
2000-07-15     2  1        
2000-07-16     1  1        
2000-07-20     0  1        
2000-07-21     1  1        
2000-07-06     1  2        
2000-07-07     2  2        
2000-07-15     0  2        
2000-07-16     0  2        
2000-07-17     2  2        
2000-07-18     1  2")[, date := as.IDate(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")]
```